# Declaração "return" não funciona dentro de forEach. Por quê?

Tags: javascript

Possuo o seguinte trecho de código, que é executado ao tentar inserir um item no `$scope.items{}`:

```
$scope.items.forEach(function(item, i) {
    if (item.codigo == $('#codigo').val()) {
        item.quantidade = parseInt(item.quantidade) + parseInt($('#quantidade').val());
        return;
    }
});
```

Porém, caso a condição seja atendida, o `return` não interrompe o restante do código.

Fora do `forEach`, o `return` funciona normalmente, impedindo que o restante da função continue sendo executado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O `return` funciona apenas para o escopo da função que está sendo chamada, no caso é o `forEach`. Para interrompê-lo você deve fazer um `for` convencional:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
    var item = $scope.items[i];

    if(item.codigo == $('#codigo').val()){
        item.quantidade = parseInt(item.quantidade) + parseInt($('#quantidade').val());
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Se você quer encontrar um item específico e mexer nele, tem métodos mais apropriados, como o [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
var item = $scope.items.find(function(item) { 
    return item.codigo == $('#codigo').val(); 
});
item.quantidade = parseInt(item.quantidade) + parseInt($('#quantidade').val());
```

Em ES-2015, mais limpo:

```
let item = $scope.items.find( item => item.codigo == $('#codigo').val() );
item.quantidade = parseInt(item.quantidade) + parseInt($('#quantidade').val());
```

Answer (score 4):

Todas as funções do [`Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) de iteração, como `forEach`, `map`, `reduce`, `filter` e `every`, não podem ser interrompidas. Em cada uma delas, o valor do `return` é usado para análise de decisão dependente da função. No caso do `forEach`, o `return` serve para pular para o próximo elemento do array.

Da documentação de [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by
>   throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method
>   is the wrong tool.

Então, se você quer iterar sobre uma parte, use a [solução do Sorack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/226337/46766), que é uma solução que te dá mais liberdade sobre um `array`.